# My program has a key error when trying to add to a list in python

Tags: python

I have a project for a python class where for a project we have to make a game where we add an item into a list. We have to collect all of the items before finishing the game. I can move between rooms just fine but I keep getting a KEYERROR when I type Item to add to the list. What would be the cause of this?

```
def show_status():
    print('You are in', location)
    print(rooms[location].get('Item'), 'Available')
    print('Possible moves:', *possible)
    print('Friends:', inventory)
    print('______________________________________')

def get_item(location, rooms, inventory):
    # add item to inventory and remove it from the room
    inventory.append(rooms[location][Item])
    del rooms[location]['Item']

rooms = {
    'Gorillas cage': {'North': 'Bear exhibit', 'South': 'Gator swamp', 'East':         'Monkeys cage', 'West': 'Lions den'},
    'Gator swamp': {'North': 'Gorillas cage', 'East': 'Fox den', 'Item':     'Toothless'},
    'Fox den': {'West': 'Gator swamp', 'Item': 'Gus'},
    'Exit': {'South': 'Monkeys cage', 'Item': 'Zookeeper'},  # villain
    'Monkeys cage': {'North': 'Exit', 'West': 'Gorillas cage', 'Item': 'Abu'},
    'Lions den': {'East': 'Gorillas cage', 'Item': 'Simba'},
    'Bear exhibit': {'South': 'Gorillas cage', 'East': 'Reptile house', 'Item': 'Icebox'},
    'Reptile house': {'West': 'Bear exhibit', 'Item': 'Sammy'}
}
location = 'Bear exhibit'
inventory = []
direction = ''
instructions()
item = rooms[location].get('Item')

while True:
    possible = rooms[location].keys() # needs to be in the while loop
    show_status() # shows possible moves and available friends in the room
    direction = input('Which direction would you like to move?').strip().capitalize()
    if direction in rooms[location].keys():
        if item is not None and direction == 'item':
            get_item(location, rooms, inventory)
        else:
            location = rooms[location][direction]
```

Comment: lets see the error with the full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have error here:

```
if item is not None and direction == 'item':
```

Should be `direction == "Item"` (capitalized) or `direction.lower() == 'item'`

and also here:

```
 inventory.append(rooms[location][Item])`
```

Item is undefined, probably you want to use "Item"